# jQuery upload multiple files

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upload multiple files via jQuery. However, the form won't serialize.

The problem I have is not getting anything when I serialize the form. It just shows nothing at all.

I do have the input type file with names like `upload_files[]`.

However, here's the actual code but modified. I am trying to get it to alert out the serialized form. So, the code I posted online is just my exact code but modified to alert out the serialized form. Right now it's alerting nothing.

I am really dumbfounded as to what the problem is. I searched the internet and found many tutorials on this. However, all of them insisted that all you need is to provide a name attribute to the input elements. The problem I have is not getting anything out of the form serialization.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/t2seL5ve/11/

code:

```
<form id="uploading_files"  name="uploading_files" action="/upload_files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <a style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:90px;">Upload files:</a>
  <div id="upload_files" style="position:absolute;top:25px;width:319px;height:180px;overflow:auto;">
  <input name="userfile" type="file" style="position:relative;left:50px;top:30px;margin:10px;">
</div>
  <input id="submit_files" name="submit_files" type="submit" value="Send" style="position:absolute;bottom:4px;left:120px;">
</form>
```

Here's the jQuery stuff:

```
$('#uploading_files').submit(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
  formData = $('#uploading_files').serialize();
   stuffman = $('[name="userfile"]').val();
  alert(formData);
});
```

Comment: You will have to handle file upload separately.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.serialize()` does not support `input` elements of type `file`.

This is also noted on the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or
>   "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file
>   select elements is not serialized.

Comment: Then how come most multiple file uploads via jquery ajax shows them using it?

Comment: If you haven't applied something like `('#...').ajaxForm(options)` (applied a special upload control to the input element) then you are attempting to serialize a standard html input element of type `file` - which isn't directly supported by `.serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Files are not being sent with the form. You'll need to write some custom code to establish that functionality. Use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It's very easy to use and saves you all the hassle to serialize the form. You can use it as:

```
var options = {
    // Here you can write all the ajax options.
}

$('#uploading_files').ajaxForm(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

php upload_files.php

```
foreach($_FILES['file'] as $attr=>$file):
    $x=0;
        foreach($file as $items):
            $files[$x][$attr]= $items;  
            $x++;
        endforeach;
endforeach;


foreach($files as $file=>$key):
        echo basename($key['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($key["tmp_name"], 'pathname here!!!!!!!!!....   /'.$key['name']);
endforeach;
```

form.php

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="uploading_files"  name="uploading_files" action="upload_files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <a>Upload files:</a>
  <div id="upload_files" >
  <input name="file[]" id="file" type="file" multiple="true" >
  </div>
  <input id="submit_files" name="submit_files" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


<div id="response"></div>

<?php// $current_dir_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); echo $current_dir_url; ?>
<script>


jQuery('#uploading_files').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var data = new FormData(this);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'upload_files.php', // check this is correct path
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#response').html(data);
                }
            }); 

        });

</script>
```

github link

https://github.com/ambrosedheffernan/simple-ajax-file-upload

Comment: I tried that and when I alert it. It shows "Object FormData" That's shown in alert. I want to see to verify if it's grabbing all the input elements inside the form. I need to see if it will grab 'userfile'  Can you post an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: console.log(formData); instead, you cant really alert a object.

Comment: I tried that too but cannot find anywhere that shows an element inside it. It'st he first time using console.log for debugging purposes. I see a bunch of protos and tostrings. I cannot find anywhere that shows elements It looks blank just an empty object but not sure about it.

Comment: its not a regular object. You cant transverse it like a js object and expect to see file names etc. But you can console.log it to create something there..it would be empty otherwise. But you can test it using this http://jsfiddle.net/t2seL5ve/13/  and using chrome network (leave open during button click) and see the files uploaded. I have two methods there, the serialize and uploading the file itself. But really you will only see the results once you attempt to upload.

Comment: Chrome network as in the web developer tools that comes with the browser? I have tried that and went to the link you gave. I still don't see anything in the network tab where it shows anything being passed. I had it opened when clicking the button where I tried uploading a image.  I still see it empty... where nothing gets passed.

Comment: yes post on the link i gave you, (try clicking twice btw, one to make the page current and second to initiate click. there are two variables you can check, data + formData (just change xhr send at the end) you should see files in the network (i tested with chrome dev tools)

Comment: All I see is : "------WebKitFormBoundary7SY3LSXdfoqVFYAm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="undefined"; filename="undefined"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
"  I tried saving a file and it does show a file name on the page. In the network section under the payload area. I see these variables.  Still don't see a file name being collected. I have clicked twice.

Comment: Content-Type: image/jpeg  == success.....not sure what you are looking for? You wont get name, etc without processing the image.

Comment: So, that shows that the file is being passed and I won't see the filename until I process it on the server side?

Comment: It works I can see the files being sent to my php file. The problem now is that the code directs me to the PHP file page. So, I get redirected to my PHP file. i don't want to do it this way. The point of using ajax is so that I don't redirect the person to my PHP page. Instead the results comes back to my original page.

Comment: you are more than likely missing `e.preventDefault();` in your js.

Comment: No, just found out it's never was working. The code broke somewhere which resulted to default. I recopied the code and pasted it in my page. The network tab shows a file but it keeps showing $_FILES as empty..  when submitting it.   that e.preventDefault(); code is in there. It looks like somewhere the code broke and resulted to the default. That's way I can see files getting passed but it would redirect me to my PHP page.

Comment: I look thru your code and found something online that's very similar. I read the tutorial located here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax    I am still using your code but trying to figure out why it's not working for me.

Comment: Here's the code exactly how it is right now: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8fc7j06c/) @David

Comment: you making it hard for yourself using ajax, the code i was using was dummy code for jsfiddle anyway...... use jQuery ajax instead for now http://jsfiddle.net/8fc7j06c/1/ ...........var_dump($_FILES) and $_POST to see what is in there.

Comment: I am still in the process on testing your code. I copied and pasted it. I ran it and for $_FILES it spits out an empty array. Yet, the code is passing these arguments:                                                                                                                  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="undefined"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
"  but on the PHP side I var_dump the files global variable and it shows an empty array.  I haven't tried the POST global variable yet. I will try it once I get time. I need to go to bed and will do it in a few days.

Comment: I just tried var_dumping $_POST global variable. It shows an empty array.

Comment: That is exactly what it shows in the network tab: It shows we are passing this to my PHP file:   "------WebKitFormBoundary9rS1DAzUsyp46CVz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="undefined"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
"

Comment: Then for both $_FILES and $_POST it's returning an empty array. that is what ends up being alerted to the screen. I copied your code exactly. After I  hit submit... I get an alert window showing me the response from my PHP which I did a var_dump for both $_FILES and $_POST at different times. Both returned an empty array.  The developer tools via google chrome under the network tab shows what we are passing to my PHP file.  which are name = file[] & filename = undefined ,

Comment: The code I have right now is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xah07zyw/1/   when running it. I get an empty array  returned for both  $_FILES  and $_POST.

Comment: yes there was a bracket missing. (use the console for correcting all js probs) i've tidied up the code a bit to comply with the original q you had which was uploading the entire form. I've also done the php as im not sure if you have that correct or not. Accept + upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: Yes, when  I copied it over it didn't copy the last bracket parts. It was in my code already just didn't copied it over. I didn't notice it until now that you brought it up. The console shows no errors. I get the alert.  The PHP is correct. I var_dump the global variables $_FILES and $_POST I tried the both and it ends up empty arrays. The code you gave me just sends 3 variables  name,file,filename, but when I ran it.. it only sends name=file[]  and filename= undefined  that's it.  the info in the headers show form-data and detects the file to be jpeg. which is accurate.

Comment: did you use the code above incl the html? it will actually upload the files for you and output the response. You just need to get the correct path to your folder and upload file. It will also output any errors. The jsfiddle was only a mock up as you cant actually use php in jsfiddle. But run the above, i sorted out filenames etc in the php code.

Comment: I am not using HTML5. what code are you referring too?

Comment: the code in the answer. It has html and js in form.php and php in upload_files.php i have also provided a link to github.

Answer (score 0):

I see the code and tried that too. It didn't work for me. I got fed up and remembered I had a old script back in 2006 where I used iframes. I got things working now. I normally want to use methods that even older browsers can support.